# Improve URL component to be better reactjs code

Tags: reactjs

Basically, this component controls a number of links within my app. These pages can be accessed by more than one type of user and as such the content in the url needs to change. In the example below, you have admin users and candidate users. The url changes because I'm using the URL `Params` to access the candidate details when accessing as admin.

This code works, however, I'd like to know if there is a better way or a more reactjs way to code this. New to reactjs, so lots to learn.

```
export default class EditCandidateProfileLinks extends React.Component {
  render() {

    if (this.props.authenticatedCandidate) {
      var contactDetails = '/candidate/edit_profile/contact_details';
    }

    if (this.props.authenticatedAdmin) {
      var contactDetails = `/admin/candidate_profile/edit/contact_details/${this.props.candidateUserId}`
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav className="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
          <LinkContainer
            activeClassName="active"
            to={contactDetails}
          >
            <NavItem>
              Contact details
            </NavItem>
          </LinkContainer>
        </Nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

EditCandidateProfileLinks.propTypes = {
  authenticatedCandidate: PropTypes.bool,
  authenticatedAdmin: PropTypes.bool,
  candidateUserId: PropTypes.string
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you have only two types of user, you can improve a little bit your code:

- just send isAdmin or not.
- if you use es6, don't forget, you've LET and CONST.

Secondly, i don't understand the name of the component : EditCandidateProfileLinks. And why is it in the plural ?

You can also transform your component as a pure function. (exemple : [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@justintulk/converting-stateless-react-components-to-pure-functions-542cd5ad3866) )

```js
const EditCandidateProfileLinks = ({ isAdmin }) => {
  let uriDetails = '/candidate/edit_profile/contact_details';
  if (isAdmin) {
    uriDetails = `/admin/candidate_profile/edit/contact_details/${this.props.candidateUserId}`;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav className="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <LinkContainer
          activeClassName="active"
          to={uriDetails}
        >
          <NavItem>
            Contact details
          </NavItem>
        </LinkContainer>
      </Nav>
    </div>
  );
}

EditCandidateProfileLinks.propTypes = {
  isAdmin: PropTypes.bool,
  candidateUserId: PropTypes.string
};
export default EditCandidateProfileLinks;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Naming isn't a strong suit and it's plural because there's more than one link in the component. Appreciate the insights.